# Loopback mysql and facebook login understanding

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, facebook, loopbackjs

I new to loop-back platform. I follow this tutorial [loop-back official tutorial for third-party](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Tutorial-third-party-login.html) and this tutorial [also a tutorial that i find](http://thecodebarbarian.com/2015/08/07/ionic-loopback-rest-api).
What i want to do is to build a rest API using loop-back as one project and a client side using angular as another project then to wrap it for mobile. In this tutorials they are using loop-back passport for make the oath connection with Facebook.

now my questions are :

1. They save all the models involved in the authentication in the memory and not in the database. is it good approach? don't i need to save all the access-tokens, identities and credentials on the database ?
2. is there another tutorial that you can direct me to or you can explain me , where in loop-back i get the information return from Facebook after authentication because i want to save it in my user model ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1.) It's not recommended to save authentication-data in memory in production, you can easily change this in server/model-config.json (or model-config.production.json) with the variable "dataSource" for each model. So instead of "memory" change it to the name of your datasource.

2.) In the example you provided, the "customProfileToUser"-function seems like an excellent place to save eventual extra data to your own User-model.

Comment: where can i find the customProfileToUser function that you mention ?

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Third-party-login-using-Passport.html#customize-loopback-user-created

Comment: It is however for Loopback 2, I'm positive it's applicable to LB3 aswell.

Comment: i see that you control in the loop-back platform. have you done a project with it ? something that i can see and learn from ? because there isn't to much examples that i can learn from . loop-back looks amazing but i find it very frustrating that i cannot find good place to see good tutorials.